# Facebook API call for posts doesn't return all data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to access all posts by a user (me) using the following GET call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/posts?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Pretty simple, however, when I do this, I'm only seeing two results  FWIW, these two results are from liking a comment/status of a public page.  Assuming the API is only giving me back recent posts, I attempted to use the Graph API Explorer to access the `next` and `previous` links in the `paging` section of the data returned.  I figured if this works, I can simply add a loop to iterate through the pages and compile all my post data.  The problem is that when I click on either link, it returns an empty JSON data set.

Any idea why I'm only able to retrieve two post records through the Facebook API?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, /feed instead of /posts is the better option.

Comment: I had tried /feed after /posts didn't provide me with what I was looking for and it had the same result.  /feed had the same two results, although it might have been spread over two pages.  Could my privacy settings have anything to do with it?  I've seen examples of public pages work and show all posts.  If that was the case, I'm not sure why I'd be seeing just 2 posts now.

Comment: Depends on the access token. If you are using your very own access token and querying your very own profile, it should display everything, including the privacy settings. You should try the Graph Explorer tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and play around with different permissions.

Comment: I'm using that tool.  What would "play around with different permissions" entail? I've also tried the Facebook SDK for .NET nuget package and creating an FQL query with the same result (almost no data).  I posted a public status about 90 minutes ago and it's still not showing up anywhere.  I'm concluding that Facebook's API is a steaming pile of shit.